# Azure AKS Load Balancer issue with Azure Network CNI plugin not accessible

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I am deploying an API application on an existing application AKS cluster which uses the `Azure CNI plugin`. The deployment manifest are native k8s with kustomize. The resources getting deployed are API deployment with an NGINX Ingress controller and couple ingress routes for API itself and grafana and prometheus(through prom operator). I have on 1 ingress route added so far which just for accessing the API.

When I deploy the resources all of them get successfully deployed and a Public IP get assigned to the controller. However, when I try to hit public IP to fetch the response for the endpoint. And I am looking for some help to troubleshoot the issue.

After looking at setup a little but I realized a couple of things:

1. Load Balancer's resource group and the nodes in the agent pools have different resource groups.
2. The NSG inbound and outbound rules are not in the same resource group.

I am not sure what piece is missing. I tried changing the resource group of the load balancer it didn't do that failing with a validation error. I also ran the same setup with the default kubenet network plugin and it worked successfully. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: What is the reason that you do not accept it? Also does not give any response?

Comment: Your suggestion on adding the service principal with Network role makes sense and that was the reason that the NSG was not getting modified with the inbound rules. I am all set. Appreciate your response. Thanks

Comment: Then you can accept it as the answer. :-)

Comment: I see you don't accept it. So what is the problem you meet or the reason you do not accept it?

Comment: I tried to upvote the answer but it says I need 15 reputation points for it. Please tell me how to accept the answer. Happy to do it.

Comment: You can see it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Load Balancer's resource group and the nodes in the agent pools have different resource groups.

The Azure AKS is an individual resource, but its components are not. You need to create the AKS cluster in a resource group. When creating the AKS cluster, Azure will create another resource group to put the components of the AKS. So there will be two resource groups when the AKS is created. Here are the [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks) to help you better understand it.

And I guess you want to assign a static public IP address to the Ingress controller and create the static public IP in the resource group which the AKS resource in, not the components. If I'm right, then you need to assign the service principal of the AKS with a network role. Here are the steps that [how to create a static public IP in another resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip).

Q2: The NSG inbound and outbound rules are not in the same resource group.

You do not need to care about the NSG inbound and outbound rules for AKS, Azure manage them itself. You just need to focus on the things that how to deploy applications in the AKS cluster.